# How to get the ID of the WordPress user

Tags: php

I'm having a lot of trouble with the PHP script below that I need to run on a .php page of my WordPress website which hosts a set of wpForo forums.

I need to obtain the field `wa_wpforo_profiles.userid` or the field `wa_users.ID` relating to the user who is logged in to the WordPress website when this script runs as a .php page of my WordPress website.

I have tried using `$user_id = get_current_user_id();` and it didn't work.

If there is anything that anybody can please do to help, I would really appreciate it.

I really am at a loss.  I don't know how to solve this problem at all but I have put at least four hours into it already.

Thanks a lot for any assistance you can provide.

```
$servername = "redacted";
$username = "redacted";
$password = "redacted";
$dbname = "redacted";

$user_id = ???;

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
//if ($conn->connect_error) {
// die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
//}

$sql = "UPDATE wa_wpforo_profiles SET groupid = 6, title = 'Subscriber' WHERE userid = $user_id";

$conn->query($sql);

$conn->close();
```

Comment: Where is this PHP file and where is it run? `get_current_user_id();` will not work unless the WordPress code setting the current user has already been run. If you're trying to access this PHP file directly then WordPress will not run at all and the function will not even exist.

Comment: You may need to include `wp-load.php` to work wordpress functions like `get_current_user_id()`. If your php file in your wordpress root folder, then you can include it as `include_once('wp-load.php');` (Nb: wp-load.php is located in wp root folder. make sure the include path is correct if your php file exist in any other folder.)

Comment: if you have updates to your question you can use the `edit` link under the tags to add the information